# Use a separate partition to host tomcat's webapps

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, partition, web-applications

I'm setting up s serie of tomcat server.
And i've read a security guide.
They say that, it's a good idea to host tomcat's webapps folder on a different partition than the rest of tomcat files.
I'm wondering if it really worst the effort.
I'm running tomcat 7 on a ubuntu install, with no additional servicve on the machine.

So is it a good idea?

edit: the document is from cisecurity.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a good idea. Putting application files, especially upload and tmp folders, on separate partitions/logical volumes is a good practice. Any folder where disk usage can grow without warning should be a separate partition. The most critical folders to protect from filling up are root (/), and /tmp. If those two fill up, things go south, and you probably can't login. /var/log is a good one to put on it's own partition as well, so that you can keep your audit trails. ideally, /boot, /, /var, and /home should each be on a separate partition.

Whether or not it's worth the trouble is your call. Resizing partitions, when one is full, can be a real pain.